# Creating a Customized Container for Slicers in PowerBI

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

Currently have a dashboard on PowerBI that uses multiple field parameters to add/remove columns on the table (example - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU1VW.jpg)). Eventually, we will deal with over 20 field parameters and additional slicers to filter the data as well. The issue: There won't be space to fit all of the slicers on the page.

What would solve this issue is having a "container/bucket" on the left side panel that stores all of the slicers. You click on this "container," which opens up a window including all of the slicers, with scrolling up/down capability.

The only way to create this visual is to develop one manually with Power BI's Software Development Kit.

https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-api

[https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/[enter](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZmdI.jpg)

The initial steps were fairly simple: Use CMD to install powerbi-visuals-api and create a new folder.
The folder contains pbiviz.json and visual.ts, both of which you have to configure to create your own visual.
I attached screenshots of the code I configured for both.

- [Visual.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vNoZ.jpg)
- [Pbiviz.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs1zK.jpg)

Havent worked much with Java before, so this has been a pain to figure out what to do and where I went wrong.

I appreciate any help that can point me in the right direction on configuring the scripts to create the type of container I need for this visual.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.